# I am getting 'Username is longer then 16 characters' when attempting to log in to a Minecraft Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have Minecraft, and when i try and join a server, it says my username is longer than 16 characters. I think it is trying to use my full email address. Is this the case? What else would cause this error, and what options do I have to try and resolve this?

Comment: **Is** your username longer than 16 chars?

Comment: Is this a problem join a *specific* server, or joining *any* server?

Answer (score 3):

This (obviously) occurs when your username is longer than 16 characters....

And this means **any** character: Any letter, punctuation mark, number, or symbol.

So, If I did "MyUSERNAMEIS12345!!!!!!!" (24 characters), it would display the above-mentioned error.

Minecraft would never need your full email address while joining servers, so I don't suppose the problem is with that. Check your username length.

Comment: What if you merged your Minecraft account with your Mojang account? You need to use your email to log into Minecraft then.

Comment: @aman207 - Doesn't make a difference. Minecraft checks your username (ign) not your email.

Comment: @Titilolo3 As < said, when you login (I go through this every login) I input my email. When I play, my username is displayed, not my email.